# realCall.cancel appears that it 'could' close my connection

Tags: okhttp

For some reason, at 27 requests per second we start to see issues sometimes with okhttp and we noticed a 5 request per host limit.  We are talking to an api that sometimes is flaky/times out, etc.

I noticed that we are not cancelling requests on timeout and they seem to be in flight still.  (ie. I want to start using RealCall.cancel)

in looking into this though RealCall.cancel calls engine.cancel() if the engine is not null which calls streamAllocation.cancel() which calls the following code...

```
public void cancel() {
   HttpStream streamToCancel;
   RealConnection connectionToCancel;
   synchronized (connectionPool) {
     canceled = true;
     streamToCancel = stream;
     connectionToCancel = connection;
   }
   if (streamToCancel != null) {
      streamToCancel.cancel();
   } else if (connectionToCancel != null) {
      connectionToCancel.cancel();
   }
}
```

This looks extremely scary as I just wanted to cancel the one request not the entire connection.  ie. just the stream http2 stream maybe but I definitely want the connection alive(I think).

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cancel before there is a stream, such as during the TLS handshake, canceling will cancel the entire connection. Once you have a stream canceling only cancels the stream.